# PHP7.1 - Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment

Tags: php, arm, shared-memory

I cross-compiled PHP7.1 for ARMv7 and enabled OPCache extension.

In php.ini:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable=0
opcache.memory_consumption=4
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=0
```

On target machine, whenever I try to run a PHP script I get:

**Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 8388608 bytes**

I made sure that system shared memory allocation is correctly configured:

```
ipcs -ml:
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 131072
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 131072
min seg size (bytes) = 1
```

Disabling the OPCache makes the PHP scripts run as it should.

Any idea please?

Comment: Have you tried not limiting the memory usage of OPCache? What happens when you remove `opcache.memory_consumption=4` from your settings?

Comment: when not limiting mem, it defaults to 128mb:
Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 134217728 bytes

Comment: OK ... the 8388608 seems to correspond to the 8MB allocated to `opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8`.  What if you restored the `memory_consumption` and reduced the `interned_strings_buffer`? Just to try to nail down the issue.